# where to set the package password property

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with **protection level - EncryptSensitiveWithPassword** and I can execute this package with in the BIDS.

While trying to deploy to file system using the Package Deployment Wizard I receive the error

> The protection level of the package requires a password but the
>   package password property is empty

Where should I set this password? (In BIDS in the designer I have set this password and while trying to open the project it even asks me for the password) So for deployment is there a another property to set?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is generally caused due to the property `PackagePassword` being empty in your configuration. Kindly **check it and if it's not set, set it**.

Also change the protection level to `DontSaveSensitive` after opening the package using the password. Then add the packages to your solution and once you are done, make the protection level as `SaveSensitiveWithPassword`.

Try deploying your package with these settings.

Reference:[Securing your SSIS Packages](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/)

Comment: But this protection level will delete all of his passwords if he has any.

Comment: True... :P ..  Though, I always use `DontSaveSensitive`. It is hassle free and provides easy deployment. Makes my life a lil simpler :D.. OP can set `PackagePassword` and check if he can deploy it or not.

Comment: Yes the PackagePassword was missing somehow. I re entered them in the BIDS designer property and build it again. On trying to install using the Package Deployment Wizard this time it prompts for the password.

Comment: er... this is a little misleading...setting this to DontSaveSensitive clearly did not solve the issue.

Comment: The steps have to be followed in order. Setting the package property to `DontSaveSensitive` will help you achieve what you want without any further problems. The problem was with the `PackagePassword` not being set as mentioned in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer by user2339071, if you don't have any passwords in your connections (i.e. you use windows trusted security) then you don't actually need a password.

But, assuming you do... (perhaps you could calrify in the original question):

My understanding is that the package password is basically specified at runtime, not deployment time.

When your DTSX file exists in the file system (after deploying it or copying it there directly), then you need to execute it somehow and that's where you specify the package password.

For example if you use SQL Agent to run your package you will find a field in the job to enter that package password. If you use DTEXEC.EXE directly, there is a switch in there for your package password also.

Personally I don't use the package deployment wizard, I just copy the DTSX file to the target file location.

Comment: Will copying the DTSX file directly works? so can I skip the DTSX package installation wizard?

Comment: It depends on how you are executing your package. Read my post again.

Answer (score 0):

Set or change the protection level of the package or packages by using a command similar to the one of the following examples:

The following command sets the ProtectionLevel property of an individual package in the file system to level 2, "Encrypt sensitive with password", with the password, "strongpassword":

dtutil.exe /file "C:\Package.dtsx" /encrypt file;"C:\Package.dtsx";2;strongpassword

The following command sets the ProtectionLevel property of all packages in a particular folder in the file system to level 2, "Encrypt sensitive with password", with the password, "strongpassword":

for %f in (*.dtsx) do dtutil.exe /file %f /encrypt file;%f;2;strongpassword

If you use a similar command in a batch file, enter the file placeholder, "%f", as "%%f" in the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily set the package password by going into the 'Package Explorer' then right click on the package to go into the properties and set your protection level there.

[image]